# Dealing with big blocklists: Is it better to DNS Blackhole or block at firewall level

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, security, internal-dns, block

Setting up some new protections for networks and I've found myself with two different options.

Due to the size of the lists (easily 2,500,000+ domains) is it better to setup DNS servers to blackhole then forward to another local DNS server then finally jump to a public DNS server for public domains or just use the firewall to block accessing these domains?

My worry is that while the DNS keeps the strain off the firewall it could add more wait time to resolve valid DNS entries due to jumping through 3 DNS servers and a massive list of domains.

Visual of my setup:

Pi-Hole ==> AD DNS Servers ==> Google DNS Servers

The idea is to block tracking, ads, scam, and other threats that the everyday user at a business has, without creating too much overhead at the sametime for day to day operations.

While blocking FB and other social sites can help, one can't prevent a user from randomly web browsing despite being told "business use only"

Comment: What kind of blacklist is this? Also Keep in mind that if you DNS block people can use raw IPs. With DNS but also with IP blacklists you also can overblock. Behind a single IP can be multiple domains and behind a single domains can be multiple URLs. If you want to control surfing behavior and filter malware a proxy solution might be more elegant.

Comment: Your black listing resolvers can directly forward to public DNS then it is no additional hop. This is also good for DNSSec validation and 6to4 translations (if needed). Domyou need to integrate AD?